# As2 Changing a Mc's Frame in Another Mc With Button

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I know it may looks like a complicated problem but i will explain to you. I have a button (instance name: bt1 for example) in main frame. And i have a movie clip (mc1) in main frame too. And i have a movieclip (mc2) inside this movie clip(mc1). How can i change mc2's frame to 2 with my button in main frame? 
I am making a rpg-like point and click game by flash with any single actionscript code knowledge. Its too hard making it with only "on press gotoandstop" codes but only with this code I have created too many options and mechanics for this game. (For example: making stats(str, dex..), experience bar) I know it would be easy to making it with codes but i cant learn them and i cant use them. (I cant memorize them:)
If you could help me with this, i would be very thankful. It helps me a lot.
(Bad for my sorry English:)

Comment: You are the man! Worked perfectly. And thanks for your suggestion too. But as i say i dont know anything about coding, and dont have much time to learn a new engine for now, i have to make this game as quick as possible. And i have history with flash. Flash gives me all i want for now. After that game i will have one free month, and will have a search for javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
on(press) {
 mc1.mc2.gotoAndStop(2)
}
```

Should do what you want.

Note that ActionScript 2.0 was "abandoned" even by Macromedia, and you will rarely have the engine available. I suggest investing your efforts in HTML5/Javascript to perform the same task, specially if you just have a two dimension kind of game. Check "game javascript engine" on google for some basis.

Comment: It worked perfectly until i moved my button from main frame to inside another movieclip. It seems button cant see the movieclip when its in another movieclip. What should i do?

Comment: It depends mostly on what program you are using, I used the CS4, looooong ago... If a movieclip has an ID, then you must use "fatherId.sonID", until you target the desired MC....Finally, if this helped you with your issue, click the `v` symbol on the left, to mark this question as answered.

Comment: Will do. I solved that. I added _parent to the code. Thank you.

Comment: Just as a last coment, when using the "program tab" (F9 if I remember), when you are issuing commands, you use the "target" button, on that tab, that will show you the available movieclips (something like this._mcX._mcY._etc...) and writtes the code as well

Comment: Yeah, thats what i exactly wanted, it was hard to write a mc's instance name in another mc's. Thanks again.